# Concern about field line equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Given a vector field $\vec{E}:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ (all kind of regularity are assumed), my book claims that the equation for field lines is
$$\frac{dx}{E_x(x,y,z)}=\frac{dy}{E_y(x,y,z)}=\frac{dz}{E_z(x,y,z)}\quad\quad\quad(1)$$

I'm struggling to get this result from the general definition of field lines, i.e. a line in $\Bbb R^3$ which is tangent to the vector field:

$$\frac{d\vec{(x,y,z)}(t)}{dt}=\vec{E}(x(t),y(t),z(t)) \quad\quad\quad(2)$$

In vector components 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=E_x(x,y,z), \frac{dy}{dt}=E_y(x,y,z), \frac{dz}{dt}=E_z(x,y,z)  $$

I'm stuck here, dealing with this differential equation. Using some (unrigousus, sorry I study physics :) ) algebraic manipulation I get the following:
$$\frac{dx}{E_x(x,y,z)}=dt, \frac{dy}{E_y(x,y,z)}=dt, \frac{dz}{E_z(x,y,z)}=dt  $$
thus from this sistem of equations you get (1).

Can anyone show me how to get (1) (which I assume is a sistem of differential form equations) from (2) in a (at least more) rigorous way?

Comment: It's an equation about differentials. Why do you think proving it using differentials is not rigorous?

Comment: @PaulSinclair dx/dt is just notation for derivative, it is not an acual division between differentials (I can write x'(t) in place of it). Dividing equation by Ex (assuming it non-zero) I get (1/Ex)(dx/dt)=1. Next step is multiplying both sides by dt: this is just a formal algebraic operation, I can't do this and it is meaningless from a mathematical prospective. I'm asking anyone to show me a rigorous path to "transform" that derivative in an equation between differentials

Comment: When $x, y, z$ are functions of $t$, then we *define* $dx = x'(t)dt, dy = y'(t)dt, dz = z'(t)dt$. (Either that, or we dive nose-deep into one of the various rigorous concepts of differentials, for all of which those equations are still true, since it wouldn't be a theory of differentials if they were false.)